# Doing a Runge-Kutta calculation for deceleration due to drag

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

Sorry, I'm new to Runge-Kutta calculations, but I'm working on a game and I believe they're what I need to better model deceleration due to drag.  Basically, I have an engine producing engineForce, and a counteracting dragForce.

For the sake of argument, I'm using a very simplistic drag equation, where dragForce = (v^2)/2.  Previously, I did acceleration like so:

$v = v + (engineForce-dragForce) * dt$

or

$v = v + (engineForce-\frac{v^2}{2}) * dt$

where dt is the timestep in the program.  This was leading to instability where velocity would suddenly drop, causing drag to drop, causing velocity to shoot back up, etc.  I believe this is due to the timesteps being too large, so something Runge-Kutta could help with.  My understanding is that the RK4 equations would be:

$k_1 = (engineForce-\frac{v^2}{2})*dt$

$k_2 = (engineForce-\frac{(v+\frac{k_1}{2})^2}{2})*dt$

$k_3 = (engineForce-\frac{(v+\frac{k_2}{2})^2}{2})*dt$

$k_4 = (engineForce-\frac{(v+k_3)^2}{2})*dt$

And putting it all together for acceleration:

$v = v + \frac{k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4}{6}$

I tried implementing it but it doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is possible that you are doing nothing wrong with RK4, try half the step size, twice the steps. If the behavior persists it is likely a feature of the exact solution. The drag force should be $-c\,\|v\|\,v$ to be physically correct.

Comment: Hey man, that totally did it!  Not sure if it's the appropriate way, but instead of doing v, v+k_1/2, v+k_2/2, and v+k_3, I did v, v+k_1/4, v+k_2/2, v+3*k_3/4, and v+k4, then made the coefficients 1,3,4,3,1 and divided by 12 instead of 1,2,2,1 and dividing by 6.  Not 100% sure why this works but it's way more stable.